Calling Yahoo Finance API in RapidAPI via axios returns error 500
I'm subscribed to the Yahoo Finance API via RapidAPI and I'm calling the API using axios like this:
 const apiKey = [MY API KEY]
 const apiURL = 'https://yahoo-finance127.p.rapidapi.com'

 const headers = {
   'x-rapidapi-key': apiKey,
   'x-rapidapi-host': apiURL
 }

 axios.get(apiURL + '/price/NVDA', { headers: headers })
   .then(response => console.log(response.data.data))
   .catch(error => console.error(error.message))

Any idea why this is returning an error 500?

an error 500 is that the full extent of the error? there's nothing in the response to explain the server error returned? (check the browser developer tools for any response body)

@JaromandaX the error request comes with this message: "Oops, an error in the gateway has occurred. If the…sue persists, please contact support@rapidapi.com"

seems rapiapi is the issue - and they suggest you contact them if the issue persists

@JaromandaX Just found the issue! RapidAPI headers do not include "https://" on the call headers. That was the problem!

Found the problem!
RapidAPI calls don't require https:// in the call headers, just the URL domain itself. Solution:
 const apiKey = [MY API KEY]
 const apiURL = 'yahoo-finance127.p.rapidapi.com'

 const headers = {
   'x-rapidapi-key': apiKey,
   'x-rapidapi-host': apiURL
 }

 axios.get('https://' + apiURL + '/price/NVDA', { headers: headers })
   .then(response => console.log(response.data.data))
   .catch(error => console.error(error.message))

